# why - will return a positive with positive?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
min_by {|a| [a.abs, -a] }
```

This is code for return minimum value closest to zero inside arrays. Positive priority
example..

```
x = [-5, 1]
x.min_by {|a| [a.abs, -a]}
==> 1
```

Here the interesting part

```
x = [-1, 1]
x.min_by {|a| [a.abs, -a]}
==> 1
```

but if

```
puts -x[1]
==> -1
```

Why puts return negative but min_by is positive? 
wasn't the -a is multiply by -1?
If it isn't, what was that?

Comment: _"wasn't the -a is multiply by -1?"_ – sure, but the block passed to `min_by` doesn't change the array values, nor does it modify the method's result. The block is merely used to determine which element should be returned. The method's result will always be an element of the collection you called `min_by` on.

Answer (score 0):

`min_by` returns the minimum in the array for your expression

-1 and 1 have the same absolute value: 1. So, `-a` is evaluated: and that's 1 and -1 respectively. And -1 is the minimum of the two. So, 1 is the minumum for `[a.abs, -a]`. Does it make sense?

```
-1 evaluates to [1, 1]
1  evaluates to [1, -1] # this is the minimum
```

so 1 is returned

Comment: Since -1 is the minimum, why it goes next to select 1?

Comment: 1 is the minimum element in the array for your expression because it evaluates to the minimum expression `[1, -1]`

Comment: so the actual value it return is -1, but with -a , it convert to positive, is that right?

Comment: It doesn't matter the value of the expression, that's used to find the minimum element of your array but it's not returned

Comment: no @nelLuffy, it returns 1, because it's the item in your array which evaluates to the minimum expression for `[a.abs, -a]`

Comment: @nelLuffy think about this `[1,2,3].min_by { |a| a + 1 } => 1`. It returns 1, not 2, because your're looking for the minimum in the array `[1,2,3]`, it doesn't matter if they evalute to `[2,3,4]` respectively

Comment: ·#a = -1, b = 1
#x[a,b]

-1 evaluates to [1, 1] #(a,b)
1  evaluates to [1, -1] # (b,a) this is the minimum·

is it?

Comment: sorry for not getting you, but instead keep asking you I like to figure it out my self, is there any part I misunderstanding and what document should I read to understand this -a?

Comment: there is nothing to understand about `-a` :D

Comment: oh yes I get it now,  { a = -1 , b = 1,  x = [a, b] }, after evaluated { a = 1, b = -1 } , thus x[1] returned.

Comment: I can't confirm because I don't understand your notation, sorry